# CSS Selector Nesting

Tags: css

Is it possible to nest selectors within selectors? I have a lot of styles that are looking like this:

```
#header h1{
  ...
} 
#header img{
  ...
}
#header form{
  ...
}
```

and I want to condense them so that they would look something like this:

```
#header{
  h1{
    ...
  }
  img{
    ...
  }
  form{
    ...
  }
}
```

in order to improve readability. Is this possible in just plain old CSS?

Comment: Its not possible in  just plain old CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not. However, if you use Preprocessors like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) (to name only the most popular ones) it is.

Depending on what you need, you should look into one of those. They are definitely worth it, since they can ease your work significantly not only with nesting selectors but also introducing variables, mixins, loops and other handy stuff.

[Introduction to and Comparison of CSS-Preprocessors](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-preprocessors/)

Answer (score 2):

Not in vanilla CSS, but there are compile-to-CSS languages like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which allow you to use nested selectors.

My library of choice is [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), which is now integrated into the Rails asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in plain CSS. You need something like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible with plain old CSS.

But you can do with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/). These two compile into CSS.

Sass produces CSS which can be indented like your required example.

```
#header{}
   #header h1{
     ...
   }
   #header img{
     ...
   }
   #header form{
     ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find things like

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .myDefinition {
    }
}
```

however. These are parsed by Firefox and can be used to provide Firefox-only CSS hacks, i am not sure though, how valid and standard-conform these are.