# How To Add Multiple CSS Properties To One CSS Id?

Tags: html, css

```
#menu1 a {
  display: block; 
  background-color: #0066FF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 20px; 
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px 5px;
} 
#menu1 a:hover {
  background-color: #0088FF;
} 
 #menu1 li {
 display: inline-block;
} 
#menu1 ul {
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding:0px;
}
```

Here's my code. I'm trying to get it all under one `#menu1` Because i'm working with multiple menu's and i don't want to lose my overview. Does anybody know how to do this? Maybe something with positioning? My question is: How do i get the a, a:hover, li and ul properties under one #menu1?

Thanks for your help!

Update:

I've had a lot of answers that refer to LESS or SASS. I'm not familiar with those languages. Could anybody explain to me what this is and how to use this? A link to a clear tutorial is fine.

Comment: ??? ..... What is the question ???

Comment: Given [Jon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27783305/82548), this question appears to be a duplicate of [CSS Selector Nesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084288/css-selector-nesting).

Comment: 'How to add multiple CSS properties to one CSS ID'.. I understood it.

Comment: @Lee the title and the question statement itself are distinct it's unclear the point

Comment: I completely disagree. Anyone would be able to work out what the poster is asking. Just because it's not exactly typed out in a simple form, doesn't mean it's not a question. It's even received a valid answer, so surely that must mean it's clear what's being asked?

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: In which case, @HYBR1D, it really does appear to be a duplicate.

Comment: Wel, @DavidThomas, I've searched around for an answer and couldn't find it. I guess i've missed that one. I've added another question about SASS and LESS too.

Comment: One possible indirect solution (hence the comment) would be to give your menus a class in addition to (or in place of) the ID value. (ie, `class="menu"`). You can then override certain values for certain menus based on which ones need specific styling.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you want to do something like this:

```
#menu1 {
    a { /* ... */ }
    li { /* ... */ }
    ul { /* ... */ }
}
```

This is not possible with CSS and there is no workaround to enable this type of structure; you have to write out each selector in full and rely on logical grouping and/or formatting in the source to provide structure.

You can, however, use a CSS preprocessor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) which will allow you to write code like the above and translate it to your original "dumb" CSS version automatically.